# Highcharts -- Dynamically apply "halo" effect to points without triggering hover event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts, is there a way to dynamically apply "halo" effect to points in scatter type charts without triggering hover event?

This is what I mean by halo:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.halo

Answer (score 1):

You can call setState function on point and then apply SELECT / HOVER.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        chart.series[0].data[2].setState('hover'); //alternatively SELECT state.
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/74s1cbmq/1/

Comment: That is cool, but the problem with it is when you hover over a point in the chart, the halo goes away.

Comment: I figured out how to leave the state on, but it looks like that highcharts restricts itself from doing a halo on more than one point too. Looks like I'll haev to go another direction for this feature, thanks for your help